# index.ts:38 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to learn typeScript.but unfortunately show index.ts:38 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier this error.but i don't understand  why show this error ।If you can give the correct answer ..
Would have benefited

my typeScript code.

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName: string, public middleInitial: string, public lastName: string) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

let user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

convert js code

```
var Student = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
    return Student;
}());
function greeter(person) {
    return "hello" + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
var user = new Student("Mohammad", "Jamil", "user");
document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

**why this error**

Comment: Working fine in typescript playground and javascript is also running in the stackover snippet

Comment: Which line of code is `index.ts:38`?

Comment: did you find solution for this problem?